# Django 1.6: How to print the number of objects a user uploaded?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to get the number of objects a user uploaded into the database. For example:

Let's say i have a model called "Link" (which adds a url with its title and description) into my models.py:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
```

With its form:

```
class UrlForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Link
```

And its view:

```
def linkurl(request):
    form = UrlForm() 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = UrlForm(data=request.POST, instance=Link()) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.instance.user = request.user 
            form.save()
            return redirect("home")
        else:
            form = UrlForm() 
    return render(request, "addurl.html", {'form': form})
```

So, knowing that the user can add urls to my app, i'm looking to print the number of urls the user uploaded into my app. Is that actually possible? 
Thank you, in advance.

Comment: The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. Use a query and pass it into your template:
   ndpu has already pointed it out here:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/22288960/659900

> ```
> user_links_count = Link.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
> render(request, "addurl.html", {'form': form, linkscount: user_links_count})
> ```

2. Use a model property which you can use to access your model over the form directly, without touching the render method in your view.
   add the following method to your link model: (warning: untested!)

> ```
> @property
> def user_links_count(self):
> try:
>     return self.objects.filter(user=self.user).count()
> except:
>     return 0 #or any error message you want
> ```

now in your template, you can access your link model directly via the form you are using. assuming you are not using an empty model:

```
{{ form._meta.model.user_links_count }}
```

However I would recommend ndpu's solution for a one off solution. Consider an enhancement to your model if you need this functionality more often

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` and `count`:

```
# change request.user to user id or user instance you need
user_links_count = Link.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
```

Comment: Oh yes, but how do I print it into a template?

Comment: @Alessandro pass it to `render` in context dict just like you did with form: `render(request, "addurl.html", {'form': form, linkscount: user_links_count})`. After it you can access `linkscount` in template: `{{ linkscount }}`